# postgres - get top category purchased by customer

Tags: postgresql

I have a denormalized table with the columns:

```
buyer_id
order_id
item_id
item_price
item_category
```

I would like to return something that returns 1 row per buyer_id

```
buyer_id, sum(item_price), item_category
```

-- but ONLY for the category with the highest rank of sales along that specific buyer_id.

I can't get row_number() or partition to work because I need to order by the sum of item_price relative to item_category relative to buyer. Am I overlooking anything obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You need a few layers of fudging here:

```
SELECT buyer_id, item_sum, item_category
FROM (
  SELECT buyer_id,
         rank() OVER (PARTITION BY buyer_id ORDER BY item_sum DESC) AS rnk,
         item_sum, item_category
  FROM (
    SELECT buyer_id, sum(item_price) AS item_sum, item_category
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY 1, 3) AS sub2) AS sub
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

In `sub2` you calculate the sum of 'item_price' for each 'item_category' for each 'buyer_id'. In `sub` you rank these with a window function by 'buyer_id', ordering by 'item_sum' in descending order (so the highest 'item_sum' comes first). In the main query you select those rows where `rnk = 1`.

Comment: ERROR:  column "sub2.item_media_type" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 5:          item_sum, item_media_type
                           ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "sub2.item_media_type" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803
Character: 165

Comment: I also wonder if it would be more easily written by just joining orders and order items, rather than work with an existing denormalized view?

Comment: There is no column 'item_media_type' in my answer, nor in your question. But the `sub` sub-query should not have the `GROUP BY` clause; see updated answer.